# How can I have a Rich text box in a custom webpart?

Tags: web-part, rich-text

In a custom Web part (actually on the home page, but I think it doesn't matter), I want to let the users input some rich content, keeping the Ribbon functionalities; same as the OOB rich text columns. This field is part a form having several fields.

By now, I have in my webpart :

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox TextMode="MultiLine" 
                             RichText="true"
                             RichTextMode="Compatible" 
                             runat="server" 
                             Rows="6"
                             MaxLength="1530" 
                             ID="myRichText" 
                             />
```

this allows me to input rich text, but using the 2007's legacy rich text input.

How can I have a new 2010 rich text input ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to change the RichTextMode to FullHTML.
SharePoint.. Prefix is referencing the right assembly?

--Update--

The InputFormTextBox control actually is a TextArea. With some script you can create a richer experience (RTE_ConvertTextAreaToRichEdit), but not the Ribbon functionalities.
Maybe the Content Editor webpart is an alternative?

--Update 2--

I just found something which maybe very helpfull to you:
http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2010/09/develop-custom-editable-visual-web-part.html

Please let me know it this answers your question.

Comment: RichTextMode value does not change the UI of the control. The prefix is actually pointing to SharePoint webcontrols namespace

Comment: Did you migrate from 2007?

Comment: no, new application from scratch

Comment: I have to embed the rich text box in a more complex form. I can't use the content editor webpart :(

Comment: Too bad, are you able to write and deploy your own controls? Then you can show the neccesary ribbon tabs from code behind.

Comment: I have no restriction on the development api. Can you points me how to show tabs from code behind ?